# Autofac Dependency Injection - Set public property

Tags: dependency-injection, asp.net-web-api2, autofac, autofac-configuration

I am building the **asp.net WebAPI project** and have used Autofac as IOC. Now i am doing constructor based injection and calls the various methods of the business class from the controller class.

Now i want to **pass some additional data into the business class via the public property IncomingUser** such as this one :-

My interface looks like this :-

```
 public interface IUserManager
    {
        string IncomingUser { set; get; }
        Task<List<String>> GetUserPofiles(string Name);
    }
```

This readonly property IncomingUser will be used inside various methods defined under the class UserManager.

```
public class UserManager : IUserManager
    {      
        public string IncomingUser { get => throw new NotImplementedException(); set => throw new NotImplementedException(); }

  public async Task<List<String>> GetUserPofiles(string Name)
        {
         ......Business Logic for the method......
        }
    }
```

From the API controller, i am setting the DI like this :-

```
 public class myAPIController : ApiController
    {

        IUserManager _Manager;

        public myAPIController(IUserManager Mang)
        {
            _Manager = Mang;
        }
    }
```

Please suggest, how should i set the property IncomingUser from the API controller class with the help of **autofac DI** or another way.

Comment: Have you [read the docs](https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/register/prop-method-injection.html)?

Comment: From what you're asking, it looks like `myAPIController` will only ever handle one user. Is that really what you want? Also, what is `IncomingUser` used for?